# Two process ids for one terminal in bash linux mint

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, linux-mint

I am running one bash terminal in linux mint. I wanted to see the process ids of running terminal.

So I tried two things:

```
ps -C 'bash'

ls -l /proc/*/exe | grep bash
```

Both of this giving two process ids. Can any one explain reason for these two process ids for only one terminal? how to identify the real process id of terminal between two?

Thanks

Comment: Note that bash is a shell – a command interpreter – not a terminal. Its _parent_, the program that draws bash's output on screen, would be the terminal. In bash, the special variables `$$` and `$PPID` expand to PIDs of the shell itself and its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Terminals *do not have* process IDs.

It is processes that have process IDs, of course.  Terminals have IDs of their own, and you'll see them in the outputs of tools like `w`, `who`, and (in the `TTY` column) `ps`.  But these are not process IDs.

The relationship between processes and terminals is not 1:1.  Moreover, as `grawity` pointed out, a *shell* is not a *terminal*.  A terminal is a device.  A shell is a program.  The `bash` program is a shell, whose input and output (in interactive mode at least) are read from and written to a terminal *device*.

Terminals on personal computer Linuxes and Unices are generally not *real*, physical, devices, plugged into a serial port of some sort.  Rather, they are either *virtual* terminals or *pseudo* terminals.  Both are the products of *terminal emulator* programs.

- In the case of virtual terminals, that program is embedded into the operating system kernel (albeit that there have been moves to change this) and it doesn't have a process ID because it isn't a distinct process in its own right.
- In the case of pseudo-terminals there's a process that manages the "master" side of the device, and displays the contents of the terminal in some fashion.  Usually it is a GUI program, such as `xterm`, `lxterminal`, `konsole`, `gnome-terminal`, or `rxvt`.  (It could, alternatively, be the SSH or TELNET daemons.)  Those do have process IDs.  But it is the terminal *emulator* that is the process, not the pseudo-terminal device.

As to why you see two `bash` processes: You have two `bash` processes running.  It's that simple.  They aren't necessarily associated with the same terminal device, or even with any terminal device.  Again, the `TTY` column in the output of `ps` will tell you what *controlling terminal* each process has.  (Terminals don't have process IDs, but in a way processes have terminal IDs.)